Could civilised hive insects build galls in living humans?
The insects form an interspecific alliance of all sufficiently advanced eusocial insects within Eastern Europe. They have access to modern day science, medicine, and philosophy
Using their knowledge and natural abilities, could the insects manipulate living human tissue to produce complex galls? The galls must have hollow chambers and insect-traversable channels to enter or exit the chambers.  The galls and the human must remain alive. Ideally the galls shouldn't take much insect-power to maintain

We've had a lot of "plausibility of..." questions lately. Honestly, they're your fictional species. Can they or not? If your answer is yes, then we'd love to help you with your [tag:creature-design] problems. If your answer is no, then there's an end to it. But asking us if they can? With so little description? Modern science can't create galls, but can your insects? You don't say. And what's the point? Are you looking for a vote on believability? VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help].

Is the human allowed to be screaming in pain the whole time?  It's not as if insects have magical abilities to manipulate tissue in ways that aren't really, really awful for the owners of the tissue.

How big are these insects? If they're tiny, then I can't imagine that there would be an issue. Bot worms and worse do this all the time. What am I missing? You seem to be looking for more than boils on the skin, though. Are you asking if ants could turn a human into a walking Acasia tree?

Can insects form a gall in ANY animal species? A quick look at definitions suggest it is a plant specific thing, Are you wanting something like what occurs in a piercing?

Change this to "how" or "would", rather than "could", and you'll be golden!

I think so
Now, there are some obvious caveats: the gall cannot be in a region where it would negatively impact the host - brain, heart, lungs etc.
The next issue is that the insects would need a way to suppress the human body's lymphatic system in the area around the gall, to prevent the host's own body from trying to fight it. (Kinda like how when a patient has a transplant, they have to take anti-rejection medication after the transplant - to stop this.)
In terms of size and complexity - humans can have large tumors sticking out of the more fleshy parts of their body and be relatively okay - and so I think this would be the option.
Then it would need access internally and externally.
Putting this all together I think we have an option:
The insects build into and around the belly-button of the individual, this allows for internal and external access, the belly has a lot of room for growth and the insects secrete a localized immuno-suppressant

Where is the "civilised" aspect of this answer? There doesn't appear to be anything deeper than what any zombie bug would do. -1, though I'd really like to change that vote!

You need societal acceptance though of bugs inside you.
You need individual acceptance of bugs inside you.
You need longterm benefits for both - for bugs inside you.
Without those benefits- a counter-group, society will involve and start spraying society with a insecticide.
To become a hive got to have benefits.
